# Proving $\frac1{2^1}+\frac2{2^2}+\cdots+\frac{n}{2^n}=2-\frac{n+2}{2^n}$ by induction

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-writing, induction

I need to prove that
$$\frac1{2^1}+\frac2{2^2}+\cdots+\frac{n}{2^n}=2-\frac{n+2}{2^n}$$ by induction.

The base case was fine, and after that we have the induction hypothesis:
$$\frac1{2^1}+\frac2{2^2}+\cdots+\frac{k}{2^k}=2-\frac{k+2}{2^k} \tag1$$
holds for any given $n=k$.

The induction step is where I get stuck. We have
$$\frac1{2^1}+\frac2{2^2}+\cdots+\frac{k+1}{2^{k+1}} \tag2$$ and by the induction hypothesis we get
$$\begin{align}
2-\frac{k+2}{2^{k+1}} + \frac{k + 1}{2^{k+1}} &=2-\frac{2(k+2)}{2^{k+1}} +\frac{k+1}{2^{k+1}} \tag3 \\[6pt]
&= 2- \frac{3k+5}{2^{k+1}} \tag4
\end{align}$$ I certainly have made a mistake somewhere, but I can’t for the life of me figure out where.

Comment: In Latex, when putting more than a single character in an exponent, you need to surround the exponent by braces. `2^{k+1}` gives $2^{k+1}$ while `2^(k+1)` only puts the first character after the "^" in the exponent: $2^(k+1)$.

Comment: The first fraction should have denominator $2^k$.

Answer (score 1):

Some simple mistake in your algebra. $-2(k+2)+k+1=-((k+1)+2)$.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to take into account the fact that the
$\dfrac{2(k + 2)}{2^{k + 1}}$
term had a negative coefficient.

Observe that
\begin{align*}
2 - \frac{2(k + 2)}{2^{k + 1}} + \frac{k + 1}{2^{k + 1}} & = 2 - \left[\frac{2(k + 2)}{2^{k + 1}} - \frac{k + 1}{2^{k + 1}}\right]\\
& = 2 - \left[\frac{2k + 4}{2^{k + 1}} + \frac{k + 1}{2^{k + 1}}\right]\\
& = 2 - \frac{k + 3}{2^{k + 1}}\\
& = 2 - \frac{(k + 1) + 2}{2^{k + 1}}
\end{align*}